# VSTS Rule Issues when trying to reset the task

Tags: azure-devops

I tried to reset the task in `VSTS`, I lost all my rules what I ever created for the task.
How to solve such issue?

Comment: What do you mean "reset the task"? How did you reset the task?

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no way to store/reset a single task with custom settings.

And there has the user voice [Build / Release Task Templates](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33744358-build-release-task-templates) which suggest store custom settings of a task into template, you can vote and follow up.

The workaround for now is create a task group to store the custom settings for a task.